# Email and Select option validation, changing label image

Tags: javascript, label

Please, if someone could help me to solve this problem.
I need to make the image "star" next to the label, changed on "check" image when email field is valid and the same thing to happens when select an option.
If the email field isn't completed or subject isn't selected the image with star rest the same.

**This is my html form ->**

```
<form id="jform" method="post" action="#" name="jform"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p> 

                    <label for="email"  id="email"  class="w_160 block req_e">E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onClick="checkEmail(document.signupform.email.value)" >
            </p>
            <p>     
                    <label for="subject" name="subject" class="w_160 block req">Subject:<!-- <span>* </span> --> </label> 
                    <select name="subject" class="subject" id="subject">
                        <option value="0">select subject</option>
                        <option value="1">subject 1</option>
                        <option value="2">subject 2</option>
                    </select>
            </p>

        </form>
```

**this is the CSS ->**

```
.req{
    background: url(images/req_star.png) 65px center no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
.req_e{
    background: url(images/req_star.png) 90px center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

.correct{
    background: url(images/valid.png) 65px center no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
.correct_e{
    background: url(images/valid.png) 90px center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
```

**JavaScript ->**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var jVal = {

        'email' : function checkEmail() {
                var email = document.getElementById('email');
                var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
                $('mail').removeClass('correct_e');
                                $('mail').addClass('req_e');
                email.focus;
                return false;
                }
                else{
                        $('mail').removeClass('req_e');
                                            $('mail').addClass('correct_e');
                    }
                }

        'subject' : function() {
        var ele = $('#subject');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        sub.css({
                top: pos.top-10,
                left: pos.left+ele.width()+40
            });

            if(form.subject.selectedIndex > 0) { // an option has been selected 
                sub.removeClass('req').addClass('correct');
                    ele.removeClass('correct').addClass('req');

            } else { // no option selected 
                    jVal.errors = true;
                    sub.removeClass('correct').addClass('req');
                    ele.removeClass('req').addClass('correct');
            }   
    }

    };

// ====================================================== //


    $('#email').change(jVal.email);
    $('#subject').change(jVal.subject);

});
```